# Prismic - set a maximum for repeatable elements in group

Tags: prismic.io

Is it possible to only allow content creators to add 1 or 2 elements in a repeatable group? I am looking for something like this:

```
     "content_teasers" : {
        "type" : "Slice",
        "fieldset" : "Content Teasers",
        "description" : "One or two teasers with Image, Title, Text and an optional link",
        "repeat": 2,
        "repeat" : {
          "image" : {
            "type" : "Image",
            "config" : {
        [...]
```

where `"repeat": 2` sets the number of allowed elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible,
The way to do it today would be to add the fields in the non-repeatable section of a slice.
I'm part of Prismic's team so I just logged this as a feature request for the dev team!
Is it because you have strict design rules of having X number of components? or you don't want to handle the display of too many cases (if they put 1, 2, or 10 items?)

Comment: we have strict design rules and i guess it could be quite confusing for content creators if they could enter more elements than we display at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into a similar problem but found a hacky solution that's been working for me (still hoping something is officially added to Prismic). If you add the number of items you want to your page ***before*** you add `"repeat": false` to your JSON config, it will keep those items but remove the ability to add more.

For anyone who comes across this, here's a snippet from one of my custom types as an example:

```json
{
  "Main": {
    "title": {
      "type": "Text",
      "config": {
        "label": "Title"
      }
    },
    "uid": {
      "type": "UID",
      "config": {
        "label": "uid"
      }
    }
  },
  "Hero": {
    "hero_images": {
      "type": "Group",
      "config": {
        "repeat": false,
        "fields": {
          "image": {...}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share an example json? this sounds interesting!

Comment: @PeterPiper Sure thing! Just updated the post to show an example